# jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision (AWS, RN)

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, jestjs, expo, aws-amplify

I have a React-native project with AWS Amplify.

In the root directory, there is an amplify folder.

Inside this amplify folder, there is a `backend` folder, and a `#current-cloud-backend` folder.

These two are basically identical.

When I try to start my project with `npm run start` I receive this error:

```
  The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
    * <rootDir>/amplify-backup/backend/function/cxLoyaltyMainAppVerifyAuthChallengeResponse/src/package.json
    * <rootDir>/amplify/#current-cloud-backend/function/cxLoyaltyMainAppVerifyAuthChallengeResponse/src/package.json
```

And it is complaining that inside these two folders, each lambda function has it's own `package.json`, in which they are named identical to their counterpart folder.

**What I have done so far**

I have found many people mentioning to put `modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/build']` inside of my root package.json under `jest`. Some also say to put it inside of `jest.config.js` which I cannot find anywhere.

I have also tried creating a root `rn-cli.config.js` and added

```
module.exports = {
   resolver: {
       blacklistRE: blacklist( [
           /node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/,
       ] )
   },
};
```

which also does not work.

I am really running out of ideas here, anyone have any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I am using the Expo CLI and was having the same problem.

The solution that worked for me:
`metro.config.js` at the root directory. (instead of `rn-cli.config.js`)

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]),
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

Comment: I'm been stuck on this problem for hours. Thank you.

Comment: Cannot find module 'metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist'

Comment: @Abinash use the answer below

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE 2022! Just change the folder of the previous answer. It´s no longer defaults/blacklist, but defaults/exclusionList. So the solution:

I am using the Expo CLI and was having the same problem.

The solution that worked for me:
`metro.config.js` at the root directory. (instead of `rn-cli.config.js`)

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]),
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below snippet in the `metro.config.js` file worked for me

I am using:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.63.4
amplify: 5.3.0

```js
 const exclusionList = require('metro-  config/src/defaults/exclusionList');
 module.exports = {
   resolver: {
     blacklistRE: exclusionList([/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]),
   },
   transformer: {
     getTransformOptions: async () => ({
       transform: {
         experimentalImportSupport: false,
         inlineRequires: false,
       },
     }),
   },
 };
```

Also, you will need to install metro-config as a dependency by running `npm i -D metro-config`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a project managed with Expo and a rule to resolve files of type cjs. I only had to include the line:

```
defaultConfig.resolve.blacklistRE = blacklist([/#current-cloud-backend/.*/]);
```

Final result:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolve.assetExts.push("cjs");
defaultConfig.resolve.blacklistRE = blacklist([/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]);

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```